# Restore bookmarks in firefox

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

Recently upgraded to ubuntu 22.04 LTS. But found that the knew firefox didn't have my old bookmarks. Is there a way to recover them?

Answer (score 3):

Your original Firefox profile should still be held within `~/.mozilla/firefox/` the contents of this is meant to be imported into the new location after the upgrade of `~/snap/firefox/common/.mozilla/firefox/`.

First, check that Firefox might just be opening the wrong profile, navigate to `about:profiles` in the address bar.

If you have multiple profiles it will list them all here and you might be able to see your old one, for example I see the default and my current profile:
[image]

If you see your profile here click `Launch profile in new browser`, once you've confirmed it's the right one click `Set as default profile` and it will be used from then on.

If your profiles don't show up there, then close Firefox and manually copy them from the old folder to the new one.

Open the directory for `~/.mozilla/firefox/` simply copy the right profile directory and paste it into `~/snap/firefox/common/.mozilla/firefox/`.

You could also copy it using the terminal like so: `cp -r ~/.mozilla/firefox/<profile directory> ~/snap/firefox/common/.mozilla/firefox/`

Once done, open FireFox and visit `about:profiles` again, set your profile as the default and restart Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

I just upgraded to 22.04 LTS and lost all my Firefox bookmarks too. I searched and found that my problem was caused by the old snap Firefox. (Yes, I has already been using snap Firefox before.) I followed the solution in the following link and get back my bookmarks, history, and everything.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1969910

The two core commands are:

```
rm -rf ~/snap/firefox
snap run firefox
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a bookmarks restore file in home/.mozilla/firefox/ ...
and when I copied it over to the snap file directory  home/snap/mozilla/firefox/ was able to restore to that set of bookmarks.  Worked very well.